# How to get a private property name with value

Tags: c#, properties

Is there anyway I can get my private property of a class from another class?
Here what I have tried.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sample aSample = new Sample();
        //Is there anyway to access that Name private property here?
    }
}

class Sample
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While you _can_ access private members with reflection, it's something that should be avoided if possible.  Do you have control of the original source code and can modify it? As was mentioned previously, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I somehow doubt that OP really wanted Reflection. It seems like a total overkill for what seems like a simple confusion about **private** and **public**. At best, you may want to suggest **internal**.

Answer (score 2):

Here i have tried with Reflection namespace and PropertyInfo class.

Please try it if you want property name with it's value. But in this case your property should be public.
  It shows all property names and their values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PropertiesImpConsoleApp
{
  class Student
  {
     //Declare variables
     string firstname;
     string lastname;

    //Define property for the variables
     public string FirstName
     {
         get
         {
             return firstname;
         }
         set
         {
             firstname = value;
         }
     }
     public string LastName
     {
         get
         {
             return lastname;
         }
         set
         {
             lastname = value;
         }
     }
  }
  class MyMain
  {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          Student aStudent = new Student();
          Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name");
          aStudent.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Enter LastName");
          aStudent.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

         //And to get the properties names you can do like this
          Dictionary<string, string> aDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

          PropertyInfo[] allproperties = aStudent.GetType().GetProperties().ToArray();
          foreach (var aProp in allproperties)
          {
              aDictionary.Add(aProp.Name, aProp.GetValue(aStudent, null).ToString());
          }

          foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in aDictionary)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
              pair.Key,
              pair.Value);
          }
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

yes make it public.

private means it is only accessible within the class

when you making it public you can access it from anywhere

```
class Sample

{

public string Name {get;set;}

}
```